# One SSL Certificate for multiple sites - CentOs 5 Apache 2.2

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl, centos5

Can I use a single certificate for two domains which are hosted on the same VPS that is using one IP address?

Answer (score 4):

Use the NameVirtualHost directive :

```
NameVirtualHost *:443
```

define your vhosts:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
  ServerName www.studyhat.blogspot.com
  DocumentRoot "/opt/apache22/htdocs/siteA"
  SSLCertificateFile "/path/to/my/cert"
  SSLCertificateKeyFile "/path/to/my/key"
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:443>
  ServerName www.studyhat.wordpress.com
  DocumentRoot "/opt/apache22/htdocs/siteB"
  SSLCertificateFile "/path/to/my/cert"
  SSLCertificateKeyFile "/path/to/my/key"
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes it is possible. This is called a Unified Communication Certificate. Refer to [this wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_SSL_certificates_for_web_servers).

Comment: I was about to answer no, citing the TLS handshake occuring prior to the http request being made, those UC certs are new on me, thanks for the info.

Comment: @Oneiroi Even without subject alternate names or a wildcard cert, there's a widely deployed TLS extension to indicate hostname.

Answer (score 0):

As detailed in [this answer](https://serverfault.com/a/350142/47187), you essentially get 3 options:

- Using a wildcard certificate: a certificate issued for `*.example.com` that would match `www1.example.com` and `www2.example.com`. Beware `*.example.com` will not match `example.com`. In addition, their usage is generally discouraged (see RFC 6215).
- Using a certificate with multiple Subject Alternative Name entries. There should be one entry per host. This is generally widely supported. How they're called commercially will depend on the CA (they're sometimes called UCC).
- Using multiple certificates via the Server Name Indication extension (allowing you to have multiple `VirtualHost *:443` with distinct `ServerName`s and `SSLCertificate` configuration). This is not supported for any version of IE on Windows XP and may cause problem with some mobile browsers too.